# how to fix conflict between 2 extensions

Tags: configurable-product, shipping, addtocart

**Edit**

I found the reason , i am using this extension : https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simpfor that reason its not displaying configurable product in cart page.

but i need this extension, please help me how to fix this without disable the plugin

**Edit end**

we are using custom shipping method in our site....

we have a **configurable products** with **associated simple products**

we have "**Add to cart" & "Buy Now Button**" in product view page

please visit [here](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/ship.html)

when we add the product to cart through "ADD TO CART" button, its adding both Configurable product and its associate product :

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

when we add the product to cart through "Buy Now button" button, its adding only associate product :

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

we created attribute "shipping charge" and entered the shipping prices there.

**we were using this code Before for shipping charges :**

```
$mpshippingcharge = 0;
 $localDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/local_shipping_distance');
 $regionalDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/regional_shipping_distance');
 $stateDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/state_shipping_distance');
```

**Configurable product shipping price = 40, 
Associated Simple product shipping price = 20**

1)If we click on "Add to cart" we were getting shipping charges as "`Total shipping charges= configurable product shipping price [40] + Simple product shipping price [20] =60 as total shipping charge`"

2)If we click on "Buy Now" button we were getting shipping charges as "`Total shipping charges= only Simple product shipping price [20] =20 as total shipping charge`"

In both cases, what we wanted is , **"Total shipping charges= configurable product shipping price [40]"** , so we used this code :

```
if (Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($proid))
 {
  continue;
 }
 $mpshippingcharge = 0;
 $localDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/local_shipping_distance');
 $regionalDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/regional_shipping_distance');
 $stateDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/state_shipping_distance');
```

1)If we click on "Add to cart" we were getting shipping charges as "`Total shipping charges= configurable product shipping price [40]`" **This is perfect.**

2) But If we click on "Buy Now" button we were getting shipping charges as "`Total shipping charges= 0[zero]`" .

**But we want the same result as ADD TO CART button.** = > ***This is the Problem***

If we use following code, than "`Total Shipping charges = Simple products shipping price`" for both Add to cart & buy now buttons.

```
if ($item->getHasChildren()){
continue;
 }
$mpshippingcharge = 0;
$localDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/local_shipping_distance');
$regionalDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/regional_shipping_distance');
$stateDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/state_shipping_distance');
```

sir, please let me know if you need any information in FTP

template path hint : [here](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/ship.html?tp=1&code=toy)

i am using following code to display "BUY NOW" button.

```
app/design/frontend/default/default/template/mpassignproduct/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml



 <?php if($assignPro['assignCount']): ?>
            <?php if($assignPro['sellerqty'] > 0): ?>

                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>

                <div style="clear: both; padding-top: 10px;">
               <button type="button" onclick="jQuery('#buy_
```

Comment: Hey, I took a look, but I am not seeing the shipping block in the cart so I can entire a zip code.

Comment: hi, please check the link now.... you can see an option in cart page to enter zip code : http://prnt.sc/ac70nw

Comment: @JerryLopez i updated the question, please check it

Comment: @BabyinMagento if I understand right, before installing any module, you only wanted to display the simple product with the configurable product in the cart ?

Comment: @DigitalPianism yes, i wanted to display both simple & configurable products in cart page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install this module.

https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple.
I hope it will help you

Comment: I updated the question, please check. when i used this plugin, than only i can not able to see "configurrable Product" in cart page

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if (Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($proid))
 {
  continue;
 }
 $mpshippingcharge = 0;
 $localDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/local_shipping_distance');
 $regionalDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/regional_shipping_distance');
 $stateDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/state_shipping_distance');

if ($item->getHasChildren()){
continue;
 }
$mpshippingcharge = 0;
$localDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/local_shipping_distance');
$regionalDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/regional_shipping_distance');
$stateDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/state_shipping_distance');
```